# How to make Vue i18n load translations from .json file in Unit Test?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-i18n

Using `vue-i18n` (v8.25.0 with `vue` v2.6.14), until now I had all my translations in `.ts` files holding the JS objects:

```js
import { LocaleMessages } from 'vue-i18n'

const translations: LocaleMessages = {
  en: {
    test: 'Test',
  },
}

export default translations
```

Now, in order to better manage the translations, I switched to using `.json` files for the translation objects and importing these json files in the code.
So the `en.json` translation file is just

```json
{
  "test": "Test"
}
```

and it is imported in a `.ts` file using

```js
import { LocaleMessages } from 'vue-i18n'
import translation from './en.json'

const translations: LocaleMessages = {
  en: translation,
}

export default translations
```

Of course, I set
`"resolveJsonModule": true,` in `tsconfig.json` to make the json-Import work.

This works when serving the application - so the translations are correctly loaded.
But when executing unit tests using `vue-cli-service test:unit`, the translations are not loaded and the following warnings are logged:
`[vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath 'test'. Use the value of keypath as default.`

This causes some unit tests to fail that assert that the English translated value is there.
Until now, these tests ran successfully but since changing to `json` files, this no longer works.

I guess, somehow jest does not load the `json` imports correctly. Is there anything I need to adjust to make jest also load the `json` translation files in test runs (an "equivalent" to `resolveJsonModule: true`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By randomly trying out different stuff, I found a solution.

I totally don't get it but here is what made it work:

Using the default `jest.config.js` with the following contents

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
}
```

made the error *appear* (translations not being available in Unit Tests).

But after adding the following two `moduleFileExtensions`, **it suddenly worked again**:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'ts',
  ],
}
```

I totally don't get it since `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel` by itself includes `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript` that defines

```js
moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx'],
```

and derives from `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/default` that defines

```js
moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    // tell Jest to handle *.vue files
    'vue'
  ],
```

(see [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets))

But for whatever reason, adding the `js` and `ts` `moduleFileExtensions` explicitly to my own `jest.config.js` made it process `json` files again.
It feels like a bug to me, though.

Comment: Additional fancy stuff - if I add `json` to the `moduleFileExtensions` array, it fails again...